# How to limit maximum number of threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I programmed a simple webserver in Java SE, without using any API. It has a GUI where you can start/stop server and see how many threads it uses.

One of requests from our teacher is that it must support multithreading, and you can control maximum threads before starting the server.

I have `WebServer` class that extends `Thread` and it runs as one thread. It has fields MAX_THREADS and a thread_counter.

WebServer:

```
public static final int MAX_THREADS = 5;
public static int threads_counter = 0;

public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {
        try {
            Socket socket = _serverSocket.accept();

            if (threads_counter >= MAX_THREADS) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                System.out.println("OVERLOAD");
            } else {
                new Handler(socket, new File(rootDir)).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WebServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WebServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

There is Handler class which also extends `Thread`. I want to limit the number of `Handler`s to MAX_THREADS.

Here is how Handler looks:

```
public void run() {
    synchronized (WebServer.class) {
        WebServer.threads_counter++;
    }
    this.setName("thread no. " +WebServer.threads_counter);
    System.out.println(this.getName());
    HandleRequest(_socket);
    synchronized (WebServer.class) {
        WebServer.threads_counter--;
    }
}
```

This does not always work as expected, however. Sometimes, it starts more than MAX_THREADS `Handler`s and I don't know how to solve it.

Could you please help me with my situation?

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/ (for example)

Comment: You need to have the counter increase and maximum check in a single block. So your thread_counter should for example be moved to the dispatcher thread-

(BTW: this is not the best solution for various things like concurrency performance or reliability. Using a thread pool will solve most of those thinbgs elegantly but I dont know how much you want to rework it)

Comment: Are you required to implement the "pooling" of threads (to realize how hard it is, maybe), or are you allowed to use some library to do that?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead of creating threads by hand, more specifically [Executors.newFixedThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29).

That way, you have more control over execution.

On other hand, in your current code, replace synchronized block and incrementing of static variable with [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet%28%29).

In spare time, take a look at [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package, it contains lots of great stuff usable for multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

You are using  `threads_counter` outside a `synchronized` block, and this field is not volatile:  you have no guarantee to read the "real" value of `threads_counter`.

However, like said in comments/answers, you should not create yourself the threads, but use a `ThreadPool` or an `ExecutorService`. It's always better to reuse such tools instead of reimplementing it.